# jquery - get html content include the wrap element

Tags: jquery

I have some HTML and I am trying to print all of it, including the panel wrap `.attrac-clone`.

Then I would like to remove the `dropdown button list` from the content.

This is what I tried to do and it is failing:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".add-attrac-2-itin", function(e) {
  var element = $(this);
  var attracHTML = element.closest('.attrac-clone').html('.attrac-clone');
  alert(attracHTML);
  var attracHTML = $(attracHTML).find('a.dropdown-toggle').remove().end();
  var attracHTML = $(attracHTML).find('ul.dropdown-menu').remove().end();
  alert(attracHTML);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-info attrac-clone" data-id="attrac-2" data-pos="">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    HEADER TITLE
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#" class="add-attrac-2-itin" data-secid="11">Add to day: Day 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="add-attrac-2-itin" data-secid="12">Add to day: Day 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">PANEL BODY TEXT</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you mean printing it out on paper? you can use mediaquery to style the page for printing only. Set the elements you don't want to print to display:none in the print.css

Comment: Why is it important where i want to print it?
i have 25K rows of code. somewhere in my code i want to print the html content

Comment: It's important because there's probably a far easier solution than the one you've asked for help. If you're printing it out - via a printer, regardless of the material - use a print stylesheet as @cloned suggests. If you use the phrase 'print' to mean something else then please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you are looking for, but this line

```
  var attracHTML = element.closest('.attrac-clone').html('.attrac-clone');
```

actually sets the div with class `attrac-clone` to the text "attrac-clone". When I set it to this, it gave the panel you were looking for.

```
  var attracHTML = element.closest('.attrac-clone').html();
```

```js
$(document).on("click", ".add-attrac-2-itin", function(e) {
  var element = $(this);

  // clone the part of the page you are trying to extract
  var attracHTML = element.closest('.attrac-clone').clone();

  // remove the menus and toggles
  attracHTML.find(".dropdown-menu").remove();
  attracHTML.find(".dropdown-toggle").remove();

  // display the resulting html
  alert(attracHTML.html());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-info attrac-clone" data-id="attrac-2" data-pos="">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    HEADER TITLE
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#" class="add-attrac-2-itin" data-secid="11">Add to day: Day 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="add-attrac-2-itin" data-secid="12">Add to day: Day 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">PANEL BODY TEXT</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, and how do i remove the dropdown button list from the content.?

Comment: not working - ` TypeError: attracHTML.find is not a function`

Comment: that's odd. It's working for me on StackOverflow, at least. What happens when you click "Run code snippet"?